# How to get product id from the products in Shopify

Tags: api, shopify, product

Inside controller I am making a call to Shopify API inorder to get the products that is :

```
@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 10 })]
```

Here I got all the product list.
Now I want to print the product id of a product .How to achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@products.each { |p| p p.id }
```

is all you need to do to print out each product id.